# Swift3のクロージャについて

Tags: swift3, alamofire

こんにちは、Swiftというかクロージャ?についての質問です。下のコードのようにAlamofire.request.responseJSON内で定義された定数をresponseJSON外でも利用できるようになる方法がもしあればご教授お願いいたします。

```
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
...
<中略>
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let urlString = "http://hogehoge.com"

    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON{ response in  
        let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
        let msg = json["key"]
        let strmsg = String(describing: msg)
    }

    print(strmsg) // error　ここでも何らかの方法で受け取ったりして使えるようにしたいです
}
...
<中略>
...
```

Comment: 非同期処理で得られた結果は必ず完了ハンドラーの中で使う、と言うのが原則です。あなたは`Alamofire.request...`で取得した`strmsg`をどう使いたいのですか?少なくともあなたが`print(strmsg)`を書いた位置では、まだ通信は終了していないわけですから、その場所で通信の結果を仕様することはできません。

Comment: > 非同期処理で得られた結果は必ず完了ハンドラーの中で使う、... 少なくともあなたがprint(‌​strmsg)を書いた位置では、まだ通信‌​は終了していない... 

なるほど、私はそこから勘違いをしていたのですね... ありがとうございます。もう少し非同期処理について学んでから設計を考えてみたいと思います。

Comment: クロージャーを使うと非同期処理が格段に書きやすくなるので、逆に学習中の方にとっては何が起こるのか起こっているのか分かりにくくなっている部分があるかもしれません。非同期処理の結果をどう使いたいのかがわかれば、もう少し適切なアドバイスができるかと思います。ご自分の中でうまく整理できたらこの質問を編集するなり新しいスレッドを立てるなりしてお尋ねください。

Answer (score -3):

セマフォを使用すると、

```
let urlString = "http://hogehoge.com"
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
var strmsg = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON{ [weak self] response in
        guard let wself = self else {
            return
        }
        let json = JSON(response.result.value!)
        let msg = json["key"]
        wself.strmsg = String(describing: msg)
        wself.semaphore.signal()
    }
    print("wait...")
    semaphore.wait()
    print("finish \(strmsg)")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

こうなると思います。
こちらを参考にしました。 [SwiftでGCDを使ってみよう！](http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2016/01/18/semaphore/)
Swift3で書き換えています。
なお、動作確認はしていません。
ご参考まで。

Comment: 早速のご返信ありがとうございます。

`wself.strmsg = String(describing: msg)`
`wself.semaphore.signal()`

の部分で **Value of type 'ViewController has no member strmsg/semaphore** と出てしまったので **wselfのguard~else文と対応する行の各wself. を削除**  して実行したのですが

`wait...`
`myProject[538:1100271] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"`

という風に出てきてfinishが出力されませんでした。試しにAlamofire.~~~内でも `print(strmsg)` をしたのですが、それも出てきませんでした。スタックオーバーフローも初心者なのでこの返し方もあっているかどうかわかりませんが...

Comment: 1. Value of type 'ViewController has... については変数のスコープを誤っていました。コードを編集しました。

Comment: 2.failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts..については、残念ながらわかりません。Alamofire.request の使用法の問題と考えますが、、、

Comment: あなたのコードはメインスレッドをブロックしてしまいます。これはiOSのアプリ作成では「絶対にやってはいけない」の筆頭と言えるものです。あなたがリンクを掲載された記事中でもAlamofireでのセマフォ使用例は「迂闊に使うと思わぬ落とし穴にハマってしまう」方の例として書かれています。(_実行しても finish とログを出力することはありません_ と明記されています。)一部を修正してなんとかフリーズは避けられたとしても、通信の間(あるいは通信状態が悪い環境で通信エラーが発生するまでの間)UIが固まってしまうようなアプリはそれだけでApp Storeでリジェクトを食らう理由になりえます。メインスレッド(`viewDidLoad()`はメインスレッドで実行されます)の中では`semaphore.wait()`はしてはいけない、と覚えておいた方が良いでしょう。